# What happened to the Installable Options when adding a printer?

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp

I am trying to add an network printer (HP Laserjet 9050) using the LPD protocol. On previous Ubuntu version I was shown a dialog box with Installable Options where I could specify total printer memory, whether it was a duplex unit, whether to use Tray 1 or Tray 4, etc.
However in Ubuntu 12.04, I am not given those options anymore. I am now unable to use the network printer.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Program for configuring printer is system-config-printer.

Try following in terminal or Alt+F2

```
$ system-config-printer
```

Comment: That's what I was doing, but never mind I found the solution.