# How to Force Ubuntu to load and use my .ppd printer driver instead of the default one?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing

I have a Dell 1815dn printer and a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.

Ubuntu recognizes the printer automatically and installs a default driver. But this driver lacks the option to bypass the toner-saver function which is very important for me since some times I want no toner-saver function as I need more contrast.

I have a propietary .ppd file from Dell that I have been using in past Ubuntu releases, and even currently in another computer with Ubuntu 12.04. But now I don't now how to force Ubuntu to skip the default driver and load and use instead the one I have (for some reason I got Ubuntu to ask me for the .ppd in the other computer, now I don't now how).

Any help on how to do this?

My prefered solution would be that the GUI asks me for the .ppd I have and load it, as I always have done. Another solution would be to know the folder in which I need to put the propietary .ppd file and know how to force Ubuntu to use it.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

- Open "Printers" from the menu (up, right), where you can can shutdown your computer;
- Right click on your Dell 1815dn printer;
- Left click on "Properties";
- In the default pane ("Parameters"), click on the "Modify" button for "Make and model";
- There, select the option "Providing a PPD file";
- Click on "Next";
- Follow the rest of the wizard.

Comment: Solved:

(I found the solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/132104/what-happened-to-the-installable-options-when-adding-a-printer)

To bring the dialog box that was present in past releases, in a terminal put:

$ system-config-printer